# Access error with MapTiler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, maptiler

[image]

[image]

Trying to add maps from the Browser > MapTiler dropdown. After adding the token as presented on the account and pressing OK nothing happens.
The very first time I tried the plugin, it worked, but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are on both the latest QGIS plugin and QGIS...
Then it should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with version 3.36 of QGIS something broke with the plugin. The moment I upgraded to 3.36, I started getting that same error despite re-installing the plugin and clearing all credentials.